# Foreach loop of ViewBag in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Would it be possible in some way to have the Price show up next to the drop down list as to not mess with the actual thing? And if so, how would one go about doing that (theoretically speaking)?

---

Have a dropdownlist that currently shows the name of an item. Trying to make it show the name + price, but I'm either getting errors or it's not saving anything to the database.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Buy()
    {
        List<ShowService.Itemss> itemlist = showklient.GetItems().ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemlist)
        {
            item.Name = item.Name + " || Price: " + item.Price + ":-";
        }
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(itemlist, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
}
```

Dropdownlist in View:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Id, "Pick item")
```

Model is as below,

[image]

What am I doing wrong/what did I miss?

As of right now, it is showing the price. But it's only sending the ItemId 0 to the database. (Updated the codes)

[image]

Comment: you don't seem to return the model to your view. Could it be you mean `return View(itemlist);`?

Comment: what is your exact error description?

Comment: @counterflux the view is already using a model, for the Buy function (@model Grupp6Sida.SaleService.Sale)

Comment: I don't know how to replicate the error but it was talking about a model being passed into directory but another one is needed. @SophisticatedUndoing

Comment: what you are doing is you are updating item in your itemlist with Name+price  but you need to pass updated model object in view. like `return View(Model object)` in your case `return View(itemlist)` i think

Comment: `ViewBag.ID = itemlist.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Value = string.Format("{0} || Price: {1:C}", x.Name, x.Price) });` (and `Price` suggests it should be typeof `decimal`, not `int`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### UPDATE:

Controller:

```
List<ShowService.Itemss> itemlist = showklient.GetItems().ToList();
ViewBag.ItemId= new SelectList(itemlist, "Id", "Name");
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ItemId", null, "Pick Item")
```

**OR**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Id, "Pick item")
```

Comment: Still just giving me the item name fetched from the database

Comment: I think you need to add to `ViewBag.Id` your `itemlist` instead of calling `showklient.GetItems()` function again. See updated answer.

Comment: Now it shows the price in the list but nothing is being saved to the database.

Comment: Yes the dropdown is 100% correct. I added a breakpoint to check what was being sent to the database and everything seemed to be in order besides the Id(primary key) which suddenly is 0 all of the time

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
List<ShowService.Itemss> itemlist = showklient.GetItems().ToList();    
foreach (var item in itemlist)
{
    item.Name = item.Name + " || Price: " + item.Price + ":-";
}
ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(itemlist , "Id", "Name");
```

In View You are using **ItemId** while binding dropdown but in your modal you don't have any property with the name of itemId so please check it once it might be **Id** property as below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Id, "Pick item")
```

Comment: I have tried something similar before and just now, it just sets the Id primary key to 0 and tries sending it to the database which leads to nothing happening

Comment: Please keep debugger and check are you getting id in itemlist list properly?